# Have two randomly selected elements match one another?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a guess the word type of game, and I am trying to make the image that is displayed be the same as the word to guess, however I have two main issues with that, one being I can not get the image to display and the second being the word and image do not match up anyways

Comment: Just a heads up that the last line `document.getElementById("gamePic".src) == selectImg;` should be `document.getElementById("gamePic").src = selectImg;` assuming you have an element with `id="gamePic"`

Answer (score 1):

"I am trying to make the image that is displayed be the same as the word to guess"? so why you random index of imgPaths

I suggest store imgPaths as key - value

```
let newGame = function () {
  let wordsArray = [
    "basketball",
    "soccer",
    "baseball",
    "hockey",
    "cricket",
    "swimming",
    "golf",
    "chess",
    "badminton",
    "skiing",
    "volleyball",
  ];

  let imgPaths = {
    "badminton": "Images/badminton.png",
    "baseball": "Images/baseball.png",
    "basketball": "Images/basketball.png",
    ...
  };

  //select random word from wordArray
  let selectedWords = wordsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsArray.length)];
  let selectImg = imgPaths[selectedWords];
  document.getElementById("gamePic".src) == selectImg;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use an array objects containing both words and images for simpler matching. Here is an example with a corrected way to change image source and an added div used for debug to show the used image source.

```js
const newGame = function () {
    const answersArray = [
    {
      word: "basketball",
      img: "Images/basketball.png"
    },
    {
      word: "soccer",
      img: "Images/soccer.png"
    },
    {
      word: "cricket",
      img: "Images/cricket.png"
    },
    {
      word: "golf",
      img: "Images/golf.png"
    },
    {
      word: "volleyball",
      img: "Images/volleyball.png"
    }
  ];

  //select random word from wordArray
  const selectedAnswer = answersArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * answersArray.length)];
  document.getElementById("gamePic").setAttribute("src", selectedAnswer.img);
  document.getElementById("gamePicSrc").innerHTML = selectedAnswer.img;
  document.getElementById("gameWord").innerHTML = selectedAnswer.word;
 }
 
 newGame();
```

```html
<div id="gameDiv">
  <img id="gamePic" src="Images/placeholder.png">
  <div id="gamePicSrc">
  
  </div>
  <div id="gameWord">

  </div>
</div>
```